# nuget 'packages' element is not declared warning

Tags: xml, visual-studio, nuget

not a showstopper but when using nuget in a project, it creates a packages.config file with this shape

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
   ... your packages
</packages>
```

this gives a warning in VS

```
The 'packages' element is not declared.
```

The origin of the problem got something to do with the xml declaration I guess.

Also I think that the default definition package shouldn't throw warnings.

Does anyone know what should I change it to so I don't get this warning? (ie even if I can see it only when the file is open, it also shows as a warning constantly with certain CA rules on.)

Comment: I found [this solution][1] for this topic, which I think is better.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833243/web-config-configsource-and-the-xxx-element-is-not-declared-warning

Comment: tbh the real solution is to add the official schema... pls see my answer below

Comment: Here is corresponding issue on github: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1836

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can always make simple xsd schema for 'packages.config' to get rid of this warning. To do this, create file named "packages.xsd":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
      targetNamespace="urn:packages" xmlns="urn:packages">
  <xs:element name="packages">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="package" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="targetFramework" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
            <xs:attribute name="allowedVersions" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Location of this file (two options)

- In the same folder as 'packages.config' file,
- If you want to share `packages.xsd` across multiple projects, move it to the Visual Studio Schemas folder (the path may slightly differ, it's  `D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Xml\Schemas` for me).

Then, edit `<packages>` tag in `packages.config` file (add `xmlns` attribute):

```
<packages xmlns="urn:packages">
```

Now the warning should disappear (even if packages.config file is open in Visual Studio).

Comment: Don't you have to modify the second line of the XSL:
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:packages" xmlns="urn:packages">

Comment: Do you know why Visual Studio is not creating that xsd file?

Comment: u missed `targetFramework` attribute in xml schema file. I m getting error `targetFramework attribute is not defined`

Comment: @harsh, You're right, schema is now updated, thanks Gerardo for fixing it.

Comment: @ŁukaszWiatrak:Please add the line `<xs:attribute name="allowedVersions" type="xs:string" use="optional" />` to your example to avoid "The 'allowedVersions' attribute is not declared' (used by modern version of NuGet).
Pedantic I know, but the whole post is about fixing a warning that has no ill effect. ;)

Comment: I found that using your solution with entity framework, the NuGet console could not parse my package.config correctly and kept telling me that the EnitityFramework package was not installed in my project. I'm using EF 6.1.0 with NuGet 2.8.50313.46 on VS2013 ultimate update 2.

Comment: On Solutions with multiple projects I get Warning "The global element 'urn:packages:packages' has already been declared". I have xsd in the same folder as the packages.config.

Comment: This solution breaks the automatic installation of missing packages feature in vs2012/nuget. The warning was gone, but it cost me hours to find out, why vs2012 doesn't install missing packages anymore. So the better solution (answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833243/web-config-configsource-and-the-xxx-element-is-not-declared-warning) is to create a schema via menu XML -> Create Schema (vs 2012 will automatically add it to the list of used schemas) - no need to change the .config, no break of other features

Comment: I had the same issue as in the previous comment: this solution broke NuGet manager in VS 2013 Update 4.

Comment: Presently, I'd add: <xs:attribute name="developmentDependency" type="xs:boolean" use="optional" />

Comment: You could create this, and then maintain it over time. We can ask why Microsoft is releasing product with warning errors but then they do this constantly.  The impact is that we have to circumvent, or investigate every build to determine whether it's "the same old warnings" or possibly a new one.  How about a more professional approach from Microsoft as a solution?

Comment: Visual Studio can automatically create packages.xsd for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774578/nuget-packages-element-is-not-declared-warning/52714797#52714797

Answer (score 194):

You will see it only when the file is open.
When you'll close the file in Visual Studio the warnings goes away

http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/261638

Comment: Ha, ignoring the problem makes it go away :D. But can what you can't see hurt you?

Comment: right @gregory we should ignore this.. there is other impact of this warning. It is generated by `nuget` and `nuget` knows how to use this file very well.

Comment: Yeah, this should be the accepted answer. The one above is one of the reasons why i have to wear a wig at work.

Comment: @neilhighley Thanks guys.  Don't quite remember the issue but glad I could help . LOL

Comment: @RyanRodemoyer Thanks guys.  Don't quite remember the issue but glad I could help . LOL

Answer (score 118):

Actually the correct answer to this is to just add the schema to your document, like so

```
<packages xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
```

...and you're done :)

If the XSD is not already cached and unavailable, you can add it as follows from the NuGet console

```
Install-Package NuGet.Manifest.Schema -Version 2.0.0
```

Once this is done, as noted in a comment below, you may want to move it from your current folder to the official schema folder that is found in

```
%VisualStudioPath%\Xml\Schemas
```

Comment: How come I can't go to that URL?

Comment: You are correct in saying that the xsd in question is not accessible currently, that said, by their W3C definition, as misleading as it might be, the xmlns (namespace) declaration is nothing more than a string in the form of a URI, and it is not required, nor suggested, that a resource be actually made available there (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace)

Comment: Interesting. Isn't there a resource somewhere though that specifies how that XML file should be? How does Visual Studio check the format?

Comment: Yes, most definitely, it is the xsd itself.  Visual Studio doesn't really validate the schema, it is the library/assembly that is consuming the XML document that will do the validation.The only reason VS needs this information is to provide intellisense.  When the resource cannot be found, VS might be using a pre-cached instance of the xsd, that can be found in %VsInstallDir%\xml\Schemas

Comment: So now I'm getting 13 Info messages ("Could not find schema info...") instead of just one Warning message... kind-of feels like a step back :-)

Comment: Nevertheless, I am using your solution because I don't like Warnings... combined with Gregory's answer, it's problem solved!

Comment: Added a note on how to install the official schema

Comment: @StefanZCamilleri - the install adds the schema to the current project it should be added to Visual Studio. I got the package using the install and then add it to the correct folder as in the accepted answer

Comment: Agreed, since NuGet does not have access to those paths.

Comment: Of note I've recently had issues with adding those namespaces screwing up NuGet. It's unfortunate as I've prefer not to have the warnings.

Comment: I believe these are wrong schemas. These schemas are for .nuspec-s, but not for packages.config. They contain declaration for <package> element in .nuspec-s, but not for the <packages>. The accepted solution above works.

Comment: It took me a very long time to figure out that adding this made nuget.exe unable to find the elements.  XML is a clownshoes file format.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is, you need a xsd schema for `packages.config`.

This is how you can create a schema ([I found it here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833243/web-config-configsource-and-the-xxx-element-is-not-declared-warning/10505471#10505471):

*Open your Config file -> XML -> Create Schema*

[image]

This would create a `packages.xsd` for you, and opens it in Visual Studio:

[image]

In my case, `packages.xsd` was created under this path:

*C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp*

Now I don't want to reference the `packages.xsd` from a Temp folder, but I want it to be added to my solution and added to source control, so other users can get it... so I copied `packages.xsd` and pasted it into my solution folder. Then I added the file to my solution:

*1. Copy `packages.xsd` in the same folder as your solution*

*2. From VS, right click on solution -> Add -> Existing Item...* and then add `packages.xsd`

[image]

So, now we have created `packages.xsd` and added it to the Solution. All we need to do is to tell the config file to use this schema.

Open the config file, then from the top menu select:

*XML -> Schemas...*

Add your `packages.xsd`, and select *Use this schema* (see below)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

None of the answers will solve your problem permanently. If you go to the path of adding XSD (From Xml menu, select "Create schema"), you will end up having problems with the package manager as it will clean up your packages.config file when you add a new package.

The best solution is just ignore by closing the file when you don't use it.

Comment: +1; just be aware that [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833243/web-config-configsource-and-the-xxx-element-is-not-declared-warning) also works (and will not break the package manager).

Answer (score 3):

This happens because VS doesn't know the schema of this file. Note that this file is more of an implementation detail, and not something you normally need to open directly. Instead, you can use the NuGet dialog to manage the packages installed in a project.

Comment: It doesn't matter that you use NuGet to install packages. The same `packages.config' file is built, and it still generates that compiler warning.

Answer (score 1):

This works and remains even after adding a new package:

Add the following !DOCTYPE above the <packages> element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE packages [
  <!ELEMENT packages (package*)>
  <!ELEMENT package EMPTY>
  <!ATTLIST package
  id CDATA #REQUIRED
  version CDATA #REQUIRED
  targetFramework CDATA #REQUIRED
  developmentDependency CDATA #IMPLIED>
]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes happens when you have an old project version. To solve it follow these steps:

1. Right click on References and select **packages.config
   toPackageReference..**
2. Click **OK**
3. Wait meanwhile project packages is updating