# How to use sections in an app.config that's in a web.config?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, app-config

My web.config looks like this:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <appSettings configSource="Exampleapp.config" />
    <connectionStrings configSource="ExampleProd.config" />
  </configSections>
<configuration>
```

My app.config (Exampleapp.config) looks like this:

```
<configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="exampleSettings">
    <section name="blah" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
    <section name="foo" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
  </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<exampleSettings>
  <blah>
    <add key="me" value="1" />
  </blah>
  <foo>
    <add key="you" value="2" />
  </foo>
</exampleSettings>
```

I'm getting an error that says: XML document cannot contain multiple root level elements. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Why don't you have `<configuration>` as the root?

Comment: @Nilesh If I put configuration, then I get an error that says: The format of a configSource file must be an element containing the name of the section.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162207/xml-document-cannot-contain-multiple-root-level-elements), you get that error because the XML document must only have **one root element** and you currently have two. Try something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
     *Your code goes here*
</config>
```

Comment: Whatever I put as the root element gives the error: The "x" element is not declared.

Comment: @dotnetN00b, take a look at the answer to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684398/the-packages-element-is-not-declared).

Answer (score 0):

As error clearly specifies,
You only need to have one root element in XML file.
Put you two parent elements in one parent element like,

```
<rootEle>

<configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="exampleSettings">
     <section name="blah" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
     <section name="foo" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
  </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<exampleSettings>
  <blah>
     <add key="me" value="1" />
  </blah>
  <foo>
     <add key="you" value="2" />
  </foo>
</exampleSettings>

</rootEle>
```

It should work.

Comment: Whatever I put as the root element gives the error: The "x" element is not declared.

Comment: I think in your **web.config** `appSettings` should be under `configuration` directly and not under `configSections`.