# VS show alot of errors (E1696, E0020) and warnings (C26451, C4754) with a new project

Tags: c++-winrt

When I starts a new project (Blank App (C++/WinRT)) on Windows10 1909 @ VS2019(up to date) its shows up a lot of errors as if the extension wasn't installed. But after trying to compile and run its works - so why do I get the errors and how can I solve this? [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REFsO.png)

---

Edit: I have fond a solution for that. its turns out that the project was needed an additional include directory:

under the project properties->C/C++->General->[Additional Include Directory]
I added the winRT folder: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt
[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48pLn.png)

and that's it now there's no errors (correction - after creating new project its still have the same errors)

---

edit2:
Update: I installed the last windows 10 SDK and was still getting the seam errors. Than I installed a package via cmd with the following command:
D:\vcpkg> vcpkg install cppwinrt:x86-windows

after this was done it seem to work now

---

edit3: 
I'm sorry for the annoying newcomer questions...
its looks like I have another problem now with my project
in the packages.config file is says that the package is not declared with the following warning [packages.config pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPvgK.png)

thanks for any help in advance.

---

(edit4) I followed this thread:
[nuget 'packages' element is not declared warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774578/nuget-packages-element-is-not-declared-warning)
and that's it, now all I have to do is to learn how to code :D

Comment: Which "new project" did you create?

Comment: C++WinRT as the tag implies

Answer (score 0):

The 'standard' include paths for Visual C++ projects are the `VC_IncludePath` and `WindowsSDK_IncludePath`. The Windows SDK includes path already has all of the directories:

```
include\<10.0.build.0>\ucrt
include\<10.0.build.0>\shared
include\<10.0.build.0>\um
include\<10.0.build.0>\winrt
include\<10.0.build.0>\cppwinrt
```

"Blank App (C++/WinRT)" is not part of the standard VS 2019 template set. The name of the project in the screenshoot is "ConsoleApplication2", which would imply  you created a Win32 console C++ project instead of a C++/WinRT project. Even still, you can reach the standard C++/WinRT headers from a Win32 console application since they are part of the standard path.

From the looks of the errors in your first screenshot, it appears you are using a generated C++/WinRT rather than the one in the Windows 10 SDK. **With VS 2019, you must add the NuGet package `Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT` to your project to get the MSBuild rules needed to build with the C++/WinRT VSIX installed, so that's likely a problem here**. See [VS Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CppWinRTTeam.cppwinrt101804264)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Chuck.  I will keep trying to configure my project once ill get the time for it.